# Calculating a derivative of a map $\mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis

This question is sort of similar to my second question here: [Proof of the Implicit Function Theorem in Baby Rudin](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2614218/proof-of-the-implicit-function-theorem-in-baby-rudin). But since that question hasn't been answered yet, I decided to post this one.

How did Rudin compute the highlighted derivative? Are there any differentiation rules for maps $E\subset \mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ which he does not mention explicitly? Or is this some triviality?

On the intuitive level it is clear that this holds, if, by analogy with a real-valued function of a real variable, one treats $x$ as the variable and $y$ as a constant, but we have a rigorous definition of a derivative of a map $\varphi:  E\subset \mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ at $x$ (namely a linear operator $L: \mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ such that $\lim_{v\rightarrow 0}\frac{|\varphi(x+v)-\varphi(x)-Lv|}{|v|}=0$), and I don't see why this holds; and even if this holds, I how can one find it (other than drawing analogy with 1 variable)?

[image]

Comment: The only thing you have to do is check if Rudin's results fulfills the definition you know. This amounts to plugging in $\phi\prime$ as $L$ into the formula you gave us and checking if the limit is indeed $0$.

Comment: I think I can see why $\phi'(x)$ is the derivative since the quotient in the definition is $$\frac{|A^{-1}(f'(x)v-f(x+v)+f(x))|}{|v|}\le\frac{||A||\times |f(x+v)-f(x)-f'(x)v|}{|v|}\rightarrow 0,$$ but the question about how one can actually compute this is still open.